# In Google Voice, why do I have to provide my existing phone number?

Tags: google-voice

I would like to sign up for a Google Voice number, so that I can send and receive SMS text messages on my computer.

When I select a Google Voice number (for example, (555) 123-4567), Google tells me that "To complete setup and start using Google Voice, you need to verify your existing phone number."

I do *not* want to tie my existing phone number (mobile number) to my Google Voice number -- I want to keep them separate.  **Will providing my existing phone number for verification tie my existing phone number to my Google Voice number?  Or is it simply to verify that I am a real person?**

Comment: I don't think any of us can provide an answer unless someone works for google for the why part

Comment: @EricF But does it tie my existing phone number to my Google Voice number?

Comment: @EricF I don't want to accidentally "hijack" my existing phone number.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126293/i-can-only-receive-call-on-the-gv-number-at-present

Answer (score 1):

### From [Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/114129?hl=en):

> In an effort to protect you from abuse, we limit the number of accounts each phone number can create.

The help page belongs to general Google account, but I believe it's the same for Google Voice.
It makes sense, since phone verification is a good way to track and limit accounts creations.

As for your question:

> Will providing my existing phone number for verification tie my existing phone number to my Google Voice number? Or is it simply to verify that I am a real person?

It's kind of both - it will be tied to your existing phone number to verify you don't abuse the system and that you're most likely a real person.