# I can only receive call on the GV number at present

Tags: google-voice

I have a google voice number linked to my iPhone number. How do activate the GV number to make calls? I can only receive call on the GV number at present

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the free Google voice app from the App Store. If you run Google Voice it shows you a call icon on the bottom. Use that to select contacts from your contact list, add new numbers, and make calls from your iPhone.